# Append ul on focus

Tags: jquery, focus, append

I have a field `#autoc1` which is used for autocomplete.

All works great but I want to add an item to the end of the generated `UL` to allow a user to add a new item should the autocomplete not find what they look for.

My thinking is to append the generated `UL` on focus in the text input so the option is always there

I'm trying the following but not working:

```
$(function() {
            $( "#autoc1" ).autocomplete({
                source: "/pages/includes/getAgent.php",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    $('#autoc1').val(ui.item.agent_name);
                    $('#comm').val(ui.item.commission_percent);
                    return false;
                }
            }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li>" )
                .append( "<a>" + item.agent_name + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul )
            };

            $('#autoc1').focus(function() {
                $('#ui-id-1').append('<li><a href="new.html">Add new</a></li>');
            });
});
```

This is auto generated html

```
<ul style="display: none; width: 360px; top: 248px; left: 856.5px;" tabindex="0" id="ui-id-1" class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <li role="presentation" class="ui-menu-item">
        <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-2">agent a</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="ui-menu-item">
        <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-3">agent b</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided I understand the situation, it would probably work cleaner if you just put your 'new item' element *after* the `<ul>` and show/hide depending on the situation. Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul style="display: none; width: 360px; top: 248px; left: 856.5px;" tabindex="0" id="ui-id-1" class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    ...
</ul>
<div id="new-item">
    <label>
        New item
        <input type="text" />
    </label>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#autoc1').focus(function() {
    $('#new-item').show();
});
```

Comment: Not the answer to the question but useful to me as it's given me a new idea quite close to what you've suggested. Thanks for that.